# how to divide the time into periods each specific variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

what im trying to do is that i have a branch that got workhours and so there is more than one services this branch give , so if the client press on service that its duration 15 minutes i need to divide the work hours of the branch into queue list of this duration , from open shift till endshift and also delete all the queues that are on breaktime of the branch

i have this variables:

Startshift="09:10" , breaktime = "12:00" , endBreak="12:30" , endShift="13:00" , period each :10min

i want to define an array of time periods that contain in each cell specific hour according to specific variable i give

myCode:

```
let startTime = 9,
    endTime = 13,
    selectedServiceDuration = 10,
    middleMin = 10;

for (i = startTime; i < endTime; i++) {

    for (j = middleMin; j < 60; j = j + selectedServiceDuration) {

        arr.push({
            id: Math.random() * 56,
            hour: i + ":" + (j === 0 ? "00" : j)
        });
    }
}
```

it will return this way

```
"hour": "9:10",
"hour": "9:20",
"hour": "9:30",
"hour": "9:40",
"hour": "9:50",
"hour": "10:10",
"hour": "10:20",
"hour": "10:30",
"hour": "10:40",
"hour": "10:50",
"hour": "11:10",
"hour": "11:20",
"hour": "11:30",
"hour": "11:40",
"hour": "11:50",
"hour": "12:10",
"hour": "12:20",
"hour": "12:30",
"hour": "12:40",
"hour": "12:50",
```

so my code missed hour : 10:00 so that mean the rest of the tabe is incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop start from 10 and terminate while `j = 50` because your condition is `j < 60`. You need to increment loop till `60` so your condition become `j <= 60`. You check `j === 0` but loop start from `10` so how it's going to `0`. Better way is check hour with `j === 60`.

Here below is modified code:

```js
const arr = [];
for(i=9; i<13; i++) {

    for(j=10; j<=60; j=j+10) {
        arr.push({id:Math.random()*56 , hour:(j === 60 ? (i + 1) : i) + ":" + (j === 60 ? "00" : j)} );
    }
}

for (var k = 0; k <= arr.length - 1; k++)
{
    console.log(arr[k].hour);
}
```

Comment: it should start whenever the shift start , if you look at the start shift it shows 09:10 so cuz that i start the loop from 10 , i put it 10 just to be static and to be more understandable , if the shift starts at 09:30 so the second loop should be from 30

Comment: @AshrafHijazy what is the value of `selectedServiceDuration`, `startTime` and `endTime`

Comment: its changeable , what im trying to do is i have a branch that got workhours and so there is more than one services this branch give , so if the client press on service that its duration 15 minutes i need to divide the work hours of the branch into queue list of this duration , from open shift till endshift and also delete all the queues that are on breaktime of the branch

Comment: does `selectedServiceDuration` is changeble?

Comment: yes , related to the type of service the client choosed , there is service that appointment took 10min and there is other services took 30min , i edited the question you can see above

Comment: @AshrafHijazy see my edited answer

Comment: thank you it works now , just i added another thing that when j==60 i should increase the i by 1 cus its moved to the next hour